# Fetch Request Form Data Shown As Null

Tags: php, ajax, switch-statement, fetch

I new to PHP and this might not even be a problem. I have a JavaScript function that sends fetch request. When I send to the api.php, I get a null when I var_dump() the variable $studentnumber. I checked the fetch request and it's sending data in the request, so there is something wrong with PHP reading the form data... maybe?. Thanks in advance this was for a school assignment.

Fetch Request

```
function login() {
    var studentnumber = document.getElementById("studentnumber");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var logindetails = new FormData();
    logindetails.append('studentnumber', studentnumber.value);
    logindetails.append('password', password.value);
    fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: logindetails,
    }
)
    .then(function(response){
        if (response.status == 202) {
            var studentnumber = document.getElementById("studentnumber");
            var logindetails = new FormData();
            logindetails.append('studentnumber', studentnumber.value);
            fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=processlogin', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: logindetails,
            });
            console.log("Success");
        } else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    })

}
```

API.PHP File

```
<?php
    include 'database.php';
    include 'session.php';

    session_start();

    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    $functions = new gaqfunctions();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
       $_SESSION['user_session'] = new gaqsession;
       http_response_code(501);
       die();
    }

    if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        switch($_GET['action']) {

        case "login":
            if($_SESSION['user_session']->userloginstatus()) {
                $studentnumber = $_POST['studentnumber'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $response = $_SESSION['user_session']->login($studentnumber, $password);
                http_response_code(206);
                if ($response == true) {
                    http_response_code(202);
                } else {
                    http_response_code(404);
                }
            } else {
                http_response_code(401);
            }
        break;

        case "processlogin":
            if($_SESSION['user_session']->userloginstatus()) {
                $studentnumber = $_POST['studentnumber'];
                var_dump($studentnumber);
                //$studentnumber = isset($_POST['studentnumber']) ? $_POST['studentnumber'] : 0;
                $_SESSION['user_session']->loginprocess($studentnumber);
                http_response_code(206);
            } else {
                http_response_code(401);
            }
        break;

        default:
            http_response_code(400);
        break;
            }
        }
        
?>
```

Comment: Is it missing in the first POST to the login? Would suggest trying to dump the whole POST to see what is there `var_dump($_POST);`. It might be deeper than expected.

Comment: Where exactly are you checking the var_dump output? I only see you logging either `Success` or `Error` there. Did you check the response in the network panel, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: `http_response_code(206)` – the 206 response code is for answering _range requests_. Not sure why you would respond with that here.